# Construction of a Kurtz random sequence that's not Martin-Löf random

Tags: reference-request, logic, computability, algorithmic-randomness

How can one construct a Kurtz random sequence that's not Martin-Löf random?

I'm also interested in the paper that included the first of such constructions.  I suspect it was in Kurtz's dissertation, but it's not very accessible.

I'd be grateful for you help in this matter.

Comment: Kurtz random sequences of words often include things like "*I watched a snail crawl along the edge of a straight razor. That's my dream; that's my nightmare. Crawling, slithering, along the edge of a straight razor... and surviving.*"

Comment: @Quinn: Well allow me to retort, "*They told me that you had gone totally insane, and that your methods were unsound.*" So Kurtz was far from normal. Besides, at 38 he finally transferred to airborne training and joined the special forces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Nies' *Computability and Randomness*, section 3.5. There he shows that every weakly 1-generic sequence is Kurtz random (Fact 3.5.4) and that weakly 1-generics fail the law of large numbers (Proposition 3.5.5). Since every Martin-Löf random satisfies the law of large numbers, one need only construct a weakly 1-generic.

Comment: Thank you.  In Rodney & Hirschfeldt, the corresponding theorems are 8.11.7 and 8.11.9.  The construction of weakly 1-generic sets is in 2.24.2.